# I'm confused about the way of writing props in vuecli

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-cli, vue-props

So I'm building a shopping cart as practice and I don't understand why one way of writing the code works and the other one does not.

This is the code that works and it shows the products perfectly:

```
  <mostrar-productos :listaPlantas="listaPlantas">
  </mostrar-productos>
```

And this one does not work:

```
  <mostrar-productos v-for="planta in listaPlantas" 
    :key="planta.id"
    :id="planta.id"
    :name="planta.name"
    :stock="planta.stock"
    :price="planta.price"
    @restar-products="restProd(id)">
```

This is the data:

```
    export default {
     name: 'App',
     data() {
       return {
          listaPlantas: [
            { id: "flor", name: "flores", qty: 0, stock: 5, price: 1000 },
            { id: "cact", name: "cactus", qty: 0, stock: 3, price: 2000 },
            { id: "arbol", name: "árboles", qty: 0, stock: 6, price: 7000 },
          ],
        };
      },
```

In my little understanding both are the same: the first one uses the complete object while the other uses attributes one by one, but it should be the same and clearly is not, but I don't understand why.

Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: Needs `mostrar-productos` source code. I recommend linking a https://play.vuejs.org/ playground.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `mostrar-productos` component getting [`name`, `stock`, `price`] as props?
receive values as props, you need to update the component as follows.

```
export default {
  name: 'mostrarProductos',
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: () => '',
    },
    stock: {
      type: Number,
      default: () => 0,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      default: () => 0,
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, but with the object listaPlantas as a prop:                                                                                                                            
    export default {
       emits: ['restar-products'],
       props: {
            listaPlantas: {
                type: Object,
            }
         },